# How are power plant discards handled in Power Grid?

Tags: power-grid

When a player purchases a power plant above the maximum limit, and must discard one, does the discard go under the stack of power plants, into a separate pile, or is it removed from the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are discarded, which pretty much means they are removed from the game.  The only time a power plant is put back under the stack of plants is during **Phase 5: Update the power plant market**.

Once a plant is discarded (because of too many plants) or removed from the game (no one bids on a plant in a turn, or someone's house count is higher than a power plant number), they aren't coming back, so "discarded" and "removed from the game" are pretty synonymous.